# Regex to allow word characters, parentheses, spaces and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a string with regex in javascript. The string can have:

- word characters
- parentheses
- spaces
- hyphens (-)
- 3 to 50 length

Here's my attempt:

```
function validate(value, regex) {
    return value.toString().match(regex);
}

validate(someString, '^[\w\s/-/(/)]{3,50}$');
```

Comment: The escape character in regular expressions is ``\``, not ``/``. And since you are using a string, you have to escape the ``\`` themselves (or make your life easy and use a regex literal).

Comment: Yes, your current regex works fine if you use the correct escape felix mentioned

Comment: You are aware that word character as defined by `\w` includes `A-Za-z0-9` and underscore `_`, right?

Comment: Inside square brackets you don't need to escape `-`, `(`, `)` etc.

Comment: @anubhava: For `(` and `)` you are right, but whether or not to escape `-` depends on its position in the character class.

Comment: @FelixKling: Agreed that `-` must appear in the end to not to be escaped.

Comment: Are you using this as a password validation mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your validator like this

```
function validate(value, re) {
  return re.test(value.toString());
}
```

And use this regex

```
/^[\w() -]{3,50}$/
```

Some tests

```
// spaces
validate("hello world yay spaces", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
true

// too short
validate("ab", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
false

// too long
validate("this is just too long we need it to be shorter than this, ok?", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
false

// invalid characters
validate("you're not allowed to use crazy $ymbols", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
false

// parentheses are ok
validate("(but you can use parentheses)", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
true

// and hyphens too
validate("- and hyphens too", /^[\w() -]{3,50}$/);
true
```

Comment: Additionally, `RegExp.test()` is probably a better choice then `String.match()` if you just want to validate.

Comment: Where in this answer do you see `str#match`? I'm using `re#test` in the `validate` method.

Comment: It's in the question: `return value.toString().match(regex);`.